# How do i get my .json file to open and be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

So i created a discord bot with a currency add, remove, leaderboard and stash and i want to add in a command called buy so people can buy tickets to a type of game. i have a json filed called inventory with this code in it

```
{"Apex":{"price":50,"type":"Pc"}, "Halo":{"price":50,"type":"xbox"}}
```

how would i make a command that opens this and checks to see if a player has enough BP for it (imaginary currency) and if they have remove how much the items cost from their stash? im not the best at python 3.6.4, so far i have

```
@client.command()

async def buy(ctx)
```

and thats it.

Comment: json.loads(json file)  to open json file then u can traverse it as dictionary